# What are the steps involved in compiling a clojure file?

Tags: clojure

I'm curious to know what actually happens when a clojure file is compiled into class files. What happens with macros when a file is aot compiled?

Is there any difference between repl evaluation and compilation?

Comment: Whether in AOT mode or not, the compiler proper never sees macros. Compiled code never refers to macros. The *reader* converts the offered text into a data structure of nested forms. Every macro-call form is replaced by its value, which ought to be another form data structure. This process is pursued until there are no macro calls left. The resulting macro-free structure is offered to the compiler proper.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the Macros Thumbnails Comment is right.
The Reader allways first evaluates the macros before anything else, like this.

[image: Evaluation Cycle of Clojure]

This is the reason some things can be done as Macro and not as a function.
Example: `or` is a Macro for a simple reason. Lets look how we would define `or` as a macro or as a function.

```
(defmacro or
  ([] nil)
  ([x] x)
  ([x & next]
      `(let [or# ~x]
         (if or# or# (or ~@next)))))


(defn or
  ([] nil)
  ([arg] arg)
  ([arg & args]
    (if arg arg (or args))
```

Now if you would try to call both functions with say `(or 1 (println :foo))` The macro would simply return 1, whereby the function would return 1 and print ":foo".

This is explained by the picture above. The reader first expands the source code, by restructuring it and then evaluates the arguments. The Function first evaluates the arguments and then the body.

The Compiling to a class would be somewhere around the evaluation Step.

Comment: I thought macros were also functions. If I defined a macro and then used it in the same namespace, how would the file be compiled?

Comment: Macros aren't functions as you can see above. You can acces macros with the same Syntax as a function. (meaning you can simply call it like (foo x y). But everytime you use a macro and compile that file, the macro gets expanded in place. To enlarge my example above: If i call the or macro anywhere in the code it gets replaced with the body of the macro and the corresponding parameters. http://pastebin.com/Ukx5NNCn  (The remaining or gets expanded further, and the then remaining or too, until there are no macros left)

Comment: What about macro definitions? Are they compiled?

Comment: Yes. A macro definition compiles into a form-transforming function accessible by name *in the compiling context*.